# Unzipping with ZipInputStream never finishes

Tags: java, android, zip, zipinputstream

I'm using an AsyncTask to unzip a file, and all seems to be going well (all the files in the ZIP archive are extracted), but my unzip method never finishes.

Here's the source for my unzip class:

```
public class MyUnzipper {


    public static boolean unzipFileIntoDirectory(String inputFilename, String outputPath) throws Exception {
        ZipInputStream zis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream dest = null;

        try {
            File archive = new File(inputFilename);
            File destinationDir = new File(outputPath);

            final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

            zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(archive), BUFFER_SIZE));
            ZipEntry entry = null;
            File destFile;
            while( (entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null ){

                destFile = new File(destinationDir, entry.getName());

                if( entry.isDirectory() ){
                    destFile.mkdirs();
                }
                else {
                    // check for and create parent directories if they don't exist
                    File parentDir = destFile.getParentFile();
                    if ( null != parentDir ) {
                        if ( !parentDir.isDirectory() ) {
                            parentDir.mkdirs();
                        }
                    }

                    int count;
                    byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    dest = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile), BUFFER_SIZE);
                    Log.i("MyUnzipper", "Beginning unzip of " + destFile);

                    while( (count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1 ){ 
                        dest.write(data, 0, count);
                        Log.v("MyUnzipper", "Count = " + count);
                    }
                    dest.flush();
                    dest.close();
                    dest = null;
                }

                zis.closeEntry();

                Log.wtf("MyUnzipper", "Unzipped entry " + entry.getName());
            }

            Log.wtf("MyUnzipper", "Unzip done");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.wtf("MyUnzipper", "Unzip error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            if( null != zis )
                zis.close();

            if( null != dest )
                dest.close();
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

When I debug this line-by-line, it runs fine until it has unzipped all files, then it gets to `zis.closeEntry()`, and the debugger just "goes away", i.e. the next line (`Log.wtf(...)`) is never executed. My AsyncTask is never finished, it's just as if I'm stuck in an infinite loop?! But looking at the source for `ZipInputStream.closeEntry()` there doesn't seem to be any loops or anything suspicious there?

I have also tried extracting the ZIP archive using `ZipFile` instead of `ZipInputStream`, but then I get the following error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: End Of Central Directory signature not found
```

There is nothing wrong with the ZIP file, I have tested it with `zip -v -T` on Mac OSx. I have also tried re-zipping it using ZIP version 3.0 and 2.1 (original was 2.0). I can unzip all version without any problems on Mac OSx (using The Unarchiver and Archive Utility).

This is driving me nuts, what can possibly be wrong?

**Update (solved)**

*Turns out to be a really stupid problem, not really related to the unzipping.*

*I'm downloading the ZIP files from a server before unzipping them, and apparently I forgot to call `close()` on the output stream from the download operation before starting the unzip operation.*

*Perhaps this thread can help someone else who makes the same stupid mistake.*

Comment: `String name = entry.getName(); zis.closeEntry(); Log.wtf(.... name);` maybe? No idea.

Comment: The problem is that execution never reaches `Log.wtf(...)` for the last file, it somehow never makes it past `closeEntry()`... so that just outputs the names of the first 11 files.

Comment: Are you using an Android [ZipInputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)? Probably [ZipArchiveInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveInputStream.html) from Apache Commons will work in your case.

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Thanks for helping, I just tried `ZipArchiveInputStream`, it gives me `java.io.IOException: Truncated ZIP file` after the last file is finished extracting - with three different ZIP-files using different ZIP-versions and zip tools!

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. Would you mind posting an example ZIP file with which you have problems?

Comment: After some further testing, it seems that the contents of the ZIP file matter. My original ZIP-file contains 12 MP3's inside a folder. If I instead put a PNG or a text file (or both) in a folder the unzip operation works as expected. But if I put one (not one of the original) MP3 file in the folder, I get `Truncated ZIP file`... So it seems that it's MP3's in the ZIP file that´s giving me problems?

Comment: @BadCash, what about file names? Are you using some non-ASCII symbols like "Я" or "字"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109243/discussion-between-badcash-and-nikolai-doronin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, sometimes your ZIP extracting code can get stuck even if you closes all previous output and input streams. And, this is [a known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73213): `ZipInputStream#read` can return 0.

***Addition:***

If your ZIP file contains some files with non-ACSII file names, you'll face problem with extracting. Android's `ZipInputStream` doesn't work well with UTF-8, CP437 and so on.

In that case Apache Commons should be a solution:

```
private boolean unpack(File zipFile, File targetDir) {
    ZipFile zip = null;
    try {
        zip = new ZipFile(zipFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        final Enumeration<ZipArchiveEntry> entries = zip.getEntries();
        while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipArchiveEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                mkdirsOrThrow(new File(targetDir, entry.getName()));
                continue;
            }
            final File entryDestination = new File(targetDir,  entry.getName());
            mkdirsOrThrow(entryDestination.getParentFile());
            final InputStream in = zip.getInputStream(entry);
            final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(entryDestination);
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (zip!= null) try {
            zip.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```